# "Someone else's", "Someone's else", and "Someone else's one"

Tags: sentence-structure, possessives, apostrophe

For example:

> -- You should move your car out of the way.
>
> -- This is not **my car** but someone else's **car.**

I want to get rid of the redundancy in the sentence which is presented by the second "car". So how can it be rephrased with being grammatically correct?

I thought of:

> This is not my car but someone else's.

But there must be a possessive noun as the apostrophe + 's' don't stand alone.

Another phrasing:

> This is not my car but someone's else.

I know this can't indicate the same meaning since "else" would act as the possessive noun, but would it be valid in this case?

And another one:

> This is not my car but someone else's one.

Substituting "car" with "one" seems suitable; however, the sentence wouldn't sound very natural and/or totally non-redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt is perfectly natural and understandable.

*Someone else* is a noun phrase, so it's quite appropriate to simply add an apostrophe and and *s* after it to indicate possession.

You also don't need to repeat the noun *car* because it's understood by parallelism as having been mentioned at the start of the sentence.

> Don't touch that **car**. It's **Mary's** <s>car</s>.
>   Don't touch that **car**. It's **someone else's** <s>car</s>.

In fact, while leaving the second instance of *car* in the sentence would be fine, it wouldn't sound as natural.

Therefore:

> ✔ This is not my car but someone else's.

Or simply:

> ✔ This is someone else's car.

Either version works, and it depends only on if you want to mention your own ownership directly or not.

---

It's unidiomatic to say *this is someone's else.* It would be interpreted as meaning an else that belongs to someone—which is nonsensical.

And while *someone else's one* is not outright incorrect, is very awkward and would not normally be used.

Comment: Thank you for addressing all the issues in the question. And the formation of the answer is adding great value for the understanding procedure.

Answer (score 1):

What you should say, and feel comfortable saying, is

> This is not my car but someone else's.

The object in question is a car, and both possessives refer to it. Suppose we replaced "someone else's" with a possessive pronoun:

> This is not my car but his.

I think this makes the relationship a little clearer. The car is not mine, it's his. You really don't even need more than a dummy subject to get the idea across:

> It's not mine, it's his.

Similarly, you can name the car owner, using the possessive form:

> It's not mine, it's Carl's.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the clarification examples. This is honestly new to me. By the way, can I use a semicolon instead of the comma in the examples you provided?

Comment: @TasneemZH: Absolutely, but a comma is less formal and more common when using short sentence splices.